# Sum all columns except first column

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to sum all columns except the first column. My HTML code is;

```
<div id="TableDetails">
                <table id="detailTable" style="width:100%">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Popname</th>
                            <th>Expense</th>
                            <th>Income</th>
                            <th>Margin</th>
                            <th>Margin Profit</th>
                            <th>Time</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="details">
                    </tbody>
                    <tfoot id="totalValues">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Total: </th>
                            <th id="totalofIncome"></th>
                            <th id="totalofExpense"></th>
                            <th id="totalofMargin"></th>
                            <th id="totalofMarginProfit"></th>
                            <th id="totalofTime"></th>
                        </tr>
                    </tfoot>
                </table>
            </div>
```

And I'm filling the tbody with for loop like this in jquery

```
for (var i = 0; i < result.Data.length; i++) {
                data += '<tr>' +
                    '<td> ' + result.Data[i].Popname + '</td>' +
                    '<td> ' + parseFloat(result.Data[i].Income.replace(",", ".")) + '</td>' +
                    '<td>' +  parseFloat(result.Data[i].Expense.replace(",", ".")) + '</td>' +
                    '<td>' +  parseFloat(result.Data[i].Profit.replace(",", ".")) + '</td>' +
                    '<td>' +  parseFloat(result.Data[i].ProfitMargin.replace(",", ".")) + '</td>' +
                    '<td>' +  parseFloat(result.Data[i].Time.replace(",", ".")) + '</td>' +
                    '</tr>';
            }
$("#details").empty().append(data);
```

I'm replacing "," with "." for sum as double.Value always come with "x.xx" I read many topics watched many videos but cant figure it out. Any help?

```
var table = $("#details");
var totalIncome = 0, // etc for the others
    $(table).find('td').not(":first").each(function () {
        totalIncome += parseFloat(this.val());
    })
```

I want to sum all columns except popname which is first column

Comment: The id in <th id="totalExpense"> is missing a closing quotation mark

Comment: `this.val()` is used for inputs - change to `this.text()`

Comment: This you need to take a look at your code, you have many type errors like `<th> id="totalofMargin"</th>`. And `<th id="totalofExpense></th>` is missing a `"`

Comment: `$(table).find('td').not(":first")` will give you all the `td`s except the very first (ie top left).  You probably want `$(table).find('td').not(":first-child")`

Comment: off topic: `var table = $("#details");` is a bad name for this variable as it would be expected to match the `<table>`, not a `<tbody>`

Comment: typos I made while opening the thread. Sorry for them. I'm fixing now

Comment: Why are you even trying to read this data back from the table to sum it up, why are you not doing this in the same place already where you are looping over the data to create the table?

Comment: @CBroe could i just add each data at for loop in totalVariable? could you show me? It's probably the answer what im looking for. I never thought about this

Comment: It looks like you want to get five separate totals, so you're gonna need to use five variables for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just sum your columns as you go through and then set the `text` of the relevant total cell:

```js
const result = {
  Data: [{
      Popname: "Row1",
      Income: "1,00",
      Expense: "2,00",
      Profit: "3,00",
      ProfitMargin: "4,00",
      Time: "5,00"
    },
    {
      Popname: "Row2",
      Income: "6,00",
      Expense: "7,00",
      Profit: "8,00",
      ProfitMargin: "9,00",
      Time: "10,00"
    },
  ]
}

let data = "";
let tIncome = 0;
let tExpense = 0;
let tProfit = 0;
let tProfitMargin = 0;
let tTime = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < result.Data.length; i++) {
  const income = parseFloat(result.Data[i].Income.replace(",", "."));
  const expense = parseFloat(result.Data[i].Expense.replace(",", "."));
  const profit = parseFloat(result.Data[i].Profit.replace(",", "."));
  const profitMargin = parseFloat(result.Data[i].ProfitMargin.replace(",", "."));
  const time = parseFloat(result.Data[i].Time.replace(",", "."));
  data += '<tr>' +
    '<td> ' + result.Data[i].Popname + '</td>' +
    '<td> ' + income + '</td>' +
    '<td>' + expense + '</td>' +
    '<td>' + profit + '</td>' +
    '<td>' + profitMargin + '</td>' +
    '<td>' + time + '</td>' +
    '</tr>';
    
   tIncome +=income;
   tExpense += expense;
   tProfit += profit
   tProfitMargin += profitMargin
   tTime += time;
}
$("#details").empty().append(data);

$("#totalofIncome").text(tIncome);
$("#totalofExpense").text(tExpense);
$("#totalofMargin").text(tProfit);
$("#totalofMarginProfit").text(tProfitMargin);
$("#totalofTime").text(tTime);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="TableDetails">
  <table id="detailTable" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Popname</th>
        <th>Expense</th>
        <th>Income</th>
        <th>Margin</th>
        <th>Margin Profit</th>
        <th>Time</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="details">
    </tbody>
    <tfoot id="totalValues">
      <tr>
        <th>Total: </th>
        <th id="totalofIncome"></th>
        <th id="totalofExpense"></th>
        <th id="totalofMargin"></th>
        <th id="totalofMarginProfit"></th>
        <th id="totalofTime"></th>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
</div>
```